# Second depth buffer in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es

I would like to implement Goldfeather's algorythm for CSG (Constructive Solid Geometry Modelling) in Open GL ES.

I need a second depth buffer and transfer (merge) operation between the buffers. I use glCopyPixels in "desktop" Open GL:

Transfer from 1st buffer to 2nd buffer

```
glViewport(0,0, _viewport.w, _viewport.h);
glRasterPos2f(_viewport.w>>1,0.0F);
glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glDepthFunc(GL_ALWAYS);
glCopyPixels(0,0,_viewport.w>>1,_viewport.h,GL_DEPTH);
```

Transfer from 2nd buffer to 1st buffer

```
glViewport(0,0, _viewport.w, _viewport.h);   
glRasterPos2f(0.0f,0.0f);
glCopyPixels(_viewport.w>>1,0,_viewport.w>>1,_viewport.h,GL_DEPTH);
```

What is the substituion of glCopyPixels in OpenGL ES?

Comment: Which version of OpenGL ES are you targeting? Already one of the answers assumes OpenGL ES 2.0. It would help if you added the tag: [opengl-es-2.0] if it is in fact an ES2 question.

Comment: If you can textures (or already are) for the depth buffers, `glCopyTexSubImage2D` might be what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have a second depth buffer in OpenGL ES -- gl.h contains only GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, not like GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1. I'm not familiar with Goldfeather's Algorithm, but I think you might be able to fake having two depth buffers by binding textures to the depth and color renderbuffer attachment points of a framebuffer, drawing what you want in the other depth attachment to the color buffer, and then finally passing those textures into a shader which draws the result you want to the screen, emulating the glCopyPixels call.

Comment: If depth information is "stored" in a texture, how can this depth information be used later for depth testing?

Comment: In Goldefeather's CSG modelling "sum of products" should be calculated in image space. Operations are executed on the entire picture. First depth puffer should be used for storing the "products", and second depth puffer should be used for storing the "sum". In this context "numbers" are the projections of geometrical primitives, "products" are created by stencil test, "addition" is a merging operation using the depth test.

Comment: You would have to reimplement the depth test you want as a fragment shader. This shader would take two sampler2D uniforms, one for each of the buffers, and you would use it to draw a full screen rectangle.